# Is there a better way to traverse the dom than call parent().parent()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this as parto of my larger code and it seems ugly and impractical

```
if (!$(this).closest( "li" ).parent().parent().hasClass('mod-left') ) {
     $(this).closest( "li" ).parent().parent().find('.checkbox').first().find('.wf-check').prop('checked', true);
     $(this).closest( "li" ).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.checkbox').first().find('.wf-check').prop('checked', true);
     $(this).closest( "li" ).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.checkbox').first().find('.wf-check').prop('checked', true);
     $(this).closest( "li" ).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.checkbox').first().find('.wf-check').prop('checked', true);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/closest/ Use closest not to nearest `li`, but to a class or ID of the parent you seek.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Most likely yes there is but we need to see the markup

Comment: and things like `.find('.checkbox').first().find('.wf-check')` can be cleaned up to `.find('.checkbox:first .wf-check')`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ says everything... Just find the correct one, or explain us in details your specific problem with code.

Comment: Make your own function findBackward that search into parents.
Or use classes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: just added a possible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$(this).parents('selector')
```

if you have a class or id above in the dom tree you can refer to.

Comment: you could just do `$(this).parents('selector')`

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you

```
$(this).parents('.class-of-any-parent').append('this is working');
```

for more details visit documentation for jquery parents() [here](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```
$(this).parents('.class-of-any-parent').find('#checkbox-id').prop('checked',true);
```

//this will search checkbox-id inside selected parent and make it checked

Comment: I really doubt this will help. Judging from the examples in the question, `.wf-check` **is not** an ancestor of `this`. If it was, there would be no reason to use `.find('.wf-check')` somewhere in the chain. But anyways, we can only know for sure if we see the HTML.

Comment: Still better to use `.closest` though.

Comment: or share your html that I can give u code with specific selectors

Comment: I didn't ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should never depend on the structure and heirarchy of your HTML when you are manipulating the DOM. In front-end work, you can think of HTML is your structural/layout layer, CSS is your presentation/styling layer and JS is your logic. Each should be separate.

When you use `$(this).parent().parent();` moving elements will break your code.

I guess what you are trying to do here is check the checkbox with class `.wf-check` in the first container with `.checkbox` class within every parent.

If that's the case, you can consider doing it that way:

```
$('.checkbox:first-child .wf-check', '.container').prop('checked', true);
```

All you need to do is replace `.container` above with a class of your upper most parent that contain all your checkboxes.

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ramynasr/8Y8v4/)